# Algorithms for efficiently computing logistic map

Tags: algorithm, numerical

The [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) is a classic example where floating point numbers fail. It's also a great example of where error propagates very badly in general in numerical algorithms even when dealing with bignums. I was wondering if there are any known algorithms for taming this issue? Is there an efficient way to compute a logistic map that doesn't require naively computing it with huge precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a classic example because it is a chaotic system.  The entire point of a chaotic system is that it shows unbelievable sensitivity to initial conditions.  To get an answer within 5% of correct after n iterations requires starting with O(n) digits of the number.  Not because your algorithm is bad, but because changing any of those digits changes what the answer should be.

So, no.  While you can potentially speed up the calculation somewhat, you can't get away with starting with lower precision.

Comment: Is there a general form for that as you increase accuracy? Like you need Omega(f(n)) digits for X percent accuracy or something? That would be an amazing answer to my question.

Comment: Also.can you provide a source for the 5% number?

Comment: @Jake This is all true on general principles about chaotic systems with the exact details highly dependent on what `r` is.  Likewise what I said about 5% is true on general principles and it wouldn't have mattered if I had said 5% or 1% or 0.1%.  The general principle is that in a chaotic system like this, with each iteration, the distance between nearby points are expanded by a constant factor `f > 1`.  Therefore after `n` steps they are separated by a factor of `f^n`.  Therefore....

Comment: ...for them to wind up within a constant distance `d` from each other after `n` steps, they had to start within `f^(-n)`.  But that means that you need to know the value to within `n*log(f)/log(10)` digits in base 10.  (This does not discount the possibility of being at one of those 0999 vs 1000 transitions...)  Which means that to get the answer to the required precision you need to know `O(n)` digits at the start.

Comment: Excellent answer! To be clear this "constant factor" is the e to the power of the "Lyapunov" exponent? And that is raised to the power of n to get an upper bound on error right?

Comment: @Jake Something like that.  But I haven't done anything with dynamical systems for a quarter century, so remember the ideas but not the terminology.